# How to connect spring boot application with using hibernate and mongodb.

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot, nosql

I already developed a website using Spring boot,hibernate and mysql. But now I want to connect with the MongoDB (Not use mysql). Which maven dependencies need to do that??? Secondly i want to know how to connect mongodb to my configuration.

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>lk.slsi</groupId>
    <artifactId>tradeportal</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>slsi-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tradeportal Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <sonar.exclusions>**/public/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--handle servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<Email Dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>      
        </dependency>
        <!--Add mysql dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--jasper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web-services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.security/wss4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-libs</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>tradeportal</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is my Application Configuration

```
spring:
  main:
    web-environment: true
    banner-mode: console
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
  application:
    name: tradeportal
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/trade_portal_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
    username: abc
    password: ****

  http:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 5MB
      max-request-size: 25MB
server:
  port: 8080
  context-path: /tradeportal
tradeportalgov:
  reportData: /reports/images
  # if file path is given relative to the webapp base use INTERNAL if the absolute path is given to baseLocation use EXTERNAL
  # EXTERNAL file download is not implemented
  filePathType : INTERNAL
  filePaths:
    baseLocation: uploads
    vat: va
```

This is my Stater

```
package lk.trad;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

/**
 * Created by ignotus on 1/22/2017.
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "lk.tradeportal")
@EnableWebMvc
@ImportResource(locations = "classpath:tradeportal-servlet-config.xml")
public class TRADEPORTALStarter extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger slsiLogger = LogManager.getLogger(TRADEPORTALStarter.class);

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        slsiLogger.info("Starting application");
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(TRADEPORTALStarter.class);
        context = application.run(args);
        application.setRegisterShutdownHook(true);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private static void closeAppContext(){
        context.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TRADEPORTALStarter.class);
    }
```

}

How can I do this.

Comment: You can't use MongoDB with Hibernate. Hibernate is a JPA provider, so they only work on top of the JDBC API, and thus only upon SQL libraries. However, you can use MongoDB with Spring Data if you use the `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`. However, from your question it's not clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: Did you see https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Comment: @g00glen00b I want to know how can i connect mongodb to my existing project... Are you sure hibernate doesn't work with mongodb

Comment: @ShanuGupta I saw that page...I want to know what is the driver class name of mongo db... I put mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver... But it goves the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 2 dependency "spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb" and "spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive".

To access Mongo databases, you can inject an auto-configured org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory. By default, the instance tries to connect to a MongoDB server at mongodb://localhost/test The following example shows how to connect to a MongoDB database:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import com.mongodb.DB;

@Component
public class MyBean {

    private final MongoDbFactory mongo;

    @Autowired
    public MyBean(MongoDbFactory mongo) {
        this.mongo = mongo;
    }

    // ...

    public void example() {
        DB db = mongo.getDb();
        // ...
    }

}
```

You can set the spring.data.mongodb.uri property to change the URL and configure additional settings such as the replica set, as shown in the following example:

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secret@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.example.com:23456/test
Alternatively, as long as you use Mongo 2.x, you can specify a host/port. For example, you might declare the following settings in your application.properties:

spring.data.mongodb.host=mongoserver
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017

and to connect spring data to mangodb you can use @Entity annotation and put a simple spring data request for Page or an Object.

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.*;
import org.springframework.data.repository.*;

public interface CityRepository extends Repository<City, Long> {

    Page<City> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    City findByNameAndCountryAllIgnoringCase(String name, String country);

}
```

Comment: where should I place your cord in my project

Comment: You have a mistake in your first sentence. You don't need both `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` and `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive`. You need to choose either one (depending on if you want reactive streams or not).

Comment: Ok...Can I use hibernate with mongodb

Comment: of course, for jpa all the databases are the same, you just have to assign the dialect and the url, or you can go through spring data it's easier, you configure the configuration file and then you start. and good luck